# limit number of watchers in asterisk BLF/subscriptions

Tags: asterisk, subscription

Our asterisk have been taking toll since number of subscriptions are too many.

is there is way to limit "watchers"

I have looked on internet but nothing specifically touches this topic of limiting number of subscriptions.

E.g.

Only max of 3 phones can subscribe to BLF/monitor to phone 001

Below is part output from our console.

```
asterisk -rx 'core show hints'

641@25550094-Default    : SIP/6172      State:Idle            Watchers  7

643@25550094-Default    : SIP/6172      State:Idle            Watchers  7

279@25790053-Default    : SIP/6128      State:Idle            Watchers  5

777@81560062-DEFAULT    : SIP/6188      State:Unavailable     Watchers  1

799@81560105-DEFAULT    : SIP/6188      State:Unavailable     Watchers  0

387@81560085-DEFAULT    : SIP/6187      State:Idle            Watchers  8

683@81560037-DEFAULT    : SIP/6188      State:Unavailable     Watchers  0

544@81560083-DEFAULT    : SIP/6188      State:Unavailable     Watchers  0

001@25550042-Default    : SIP/6129      State:Idle            Watchers 13

002@25550042-Default    : SIP/6129      State:Idle            Watchers 13
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no way.

You should think about moving to kamailio/opensips and clustering.